# What is the 3 click sound when the autopilot is disconnected on Airbus aircraft?

Tags: autopilot, airbus

On Airbus aircraft what is the 3 click tone that sounds once autopilot is disconnected? I have tried researching on the internet but could not find anything

Comment: To inform the crew the [A/P is now inactive](http://www.zedge.net/ringtone/1740744/)? Disconnection may result from a fault, or an unintentional action.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Aviation.SE. I'm sorry, but we seem to have been suddenly invaded by downvotopaths. [What's wrong with this question?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/what-should-we-do-about-question-that-is-readily-answered-on-internet).  +1 from me since I see this as a perfectly legitimate question and just to restore the natural balance of the stack-o-verse.

Comment: Are you looking for a recording of the sound?

Comment: I believe that sound was invented by Airbus specifically for signaling autopilot disconnect.

Comment: Sorry guys I think you misunderstood, I meant that one autopilot is disconnected there is a three click tone "bleep bleep bleep" after that there is another one it's like "bink bink bink"

Comment: Are you asking for sounds in a simulator (which one) or a real aircraft? Does that happen each time the A/P is disconnected manually and while the aircraft is within the regular flight envelop?

Comment: If you can include a link to a YouTube video and a marker of the sound you're describing, that would make the question much more clear.

Comment: https://youtu.be/XU3B8Qq1niY This video at 2.55

Comment: This  sound just after "approaching minimums" announcement ([in your linked video](https://youtu.be/XU3B8Qq1niY?t=2m50s)) is the [sound linked in the first comment](http://www.zedge.net/ringtone/1740744/). so "*sorry guys I think you misunderstood...*" has been and is still confusing.

Comment: Thanks for that link @mins. I've been looking for that ringtone

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two separate aural warnings that you might be referring to: one is indeed called 'Triple Click' and consists of three brief clicks, but is emitted when the landing capability becomes degraded or the autopilot otherwise changes mode.

The warning generated upon autopilot disconnection, instead, is the so-called 'Cavalry Charge' and consists of three longer beeping sounds; it's either played once or repeated continuously (cases 1 and 2 below).

From a table in the Airbus A320 FCOM, DSC-31-10 P 4/6:

> **TRIPLE CLICK**
>
> Meaning: Landing capability downgrade or some cases of mode reversion.
>
> Duration: 0.5 s (3 pulses)
>
> **CAVALRY CHARGE**
>
> Meaning:
>
> 1. A/P disconnection by takeover push-button.
> 2. A/P disconnection due to failure.
>
> Duration:
>
> 1. 1.5 s
> 2. Permanent
>
> Cancellation:
>
> 1. Second push on takeover push-button.
> 2. Press Master Warning light or takeover push-button.

See [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/XU3B8Qq1niY?t=2m50s) (at 2:52) for a cavalry charge immediately followed by a triple click (thank you [Jack](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/22978/jack)).

Comment: https://youtu.be/XU3B8Qq1niY This video at 2.55

Comment: Any idea why they call that a "cavalry charge?" It doesn't really make me think of the standard bugle charge.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, the Flight Crew Techniques Manual describes the **TRIPLE CLICK** as:

> ...an attention-getter, designed to draw the flight crew's attention to the FMA.

The FMA will show a mode change or reversion by putting a white box around the new mode and pulsing the associated FD bar.